# external link not working javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some basic javascript that was originally in the html file but then I have put it in an external file and it is not working, I am not sure why. I have put the script just before the closing body tag.

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/2fuxR/

HTML

```
   <body>

  <div class="titleBar"><img src="../assets/images/gallery.png" alt=""></div>
  <div id="display">
  <img id="displayimg">
  </div>
  <div id="select">
  <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery1.png"        onclick='javascript:display(this)'>

    <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery2.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
    <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery3.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
    <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery4.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
    <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery5.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
    <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery6.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 function display(imgElement){
   document.getElementById('displayimg').setAttribute('src',imgElement.getAttribute('src'));
```

Comment: Well, to start you have syntax errors, your function is not closed, and your fiddle is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the `}` at end of jscript function
and try adding a slash to your js src `<script src="/script.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

i have test is in my native environment ,it works  well!
you just need to pay attention to the path of the external js file
and check your js function's syntax ,firebug and chrome developer tool may be a good helper

Answer (score 0):

Your jsFiddle framework & extensions set the no - library and onLoad

chaged jsFiddle framework & extensions set no - library and no wrap in .

edit your html code.

try it

```
<div id="display">   
    <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery2.png" onclick='display(this)'/>
    <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery3.png" onclick='display(this)'/>
    <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery4.png" onclick='display(this)'/>
    <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery5.png" onclick='display(this)'/>
    <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/gallery6.png" onclick='display(this)'/>
</div>
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/WonSeokHan/2L9ar/